# Library for SVM and ANN with graphical toolkit

Tags: opencv, artificial-intelligence, kinect, svm

Well Hello everybody. I am doing a project that consist in dectect objects using kinect and svm and ann machine learning. I want if it is posible to give the names of library for svm and ann with graphical tool because I want only to train ann with that library and save in .xml then load .xml with opencv!!

Comment: What's wrong with the OpenCV implementations of [ANN](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html?highlight=ann#cvann-mlp) and [SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html?highlight=svm#cvsvm)?

Comment: Hi..The problem is that I dont know how to convert images as input for svm and ann!! I read about to use positives and negatives images to use for svm but I dont understand how convert that images to input and I read about ann and say that I need input images and ouput images and ann search the relantionship but I dont know how to convert images to input

Comment: It seems like you need to read up on SVM and ANN theory. They need **features** as input, not the image(s).. The **image intensities** can be features, but they are generally the most basic feature and don't work that well. In conclusion, you will need to cater the features to the dataset in questions and then use those to train your classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM is a classifier used to classify samples based upon their feature vectors. So, your task is to convert the images into feature vectors which can be used by SVM for its training and testing.

Ok, to create feature vector from your images there are several possibilites and i am going to mention some very common technique:

1. A very easy method is to create normalized hue-histogram of your each image. Let's say, you have created hue-histogram with 5-bins. So, based upon your image color there will be some values in these 5 bins. Lets say the values look like this { 0.32 0.56 0 0 0.12 }. So, now this is your one input vector with 5 dimensions (i.e. number of bins). You have to do the same procedure for all training samples and then you will do it for test image too.
2. Extract some feature from your input samples (e.g. by using SIFT, SURf) and then create there descriptor using SIFT/SURF. And, then you can use these descriptors as the input to your SVM for training.

Comment: ah Ok I understand!! If I want that my software detect apple and I use SURF and VSM to train with a lot of images and in case that I have a apple image that is smaller than images that I gave to train , my software can detect that is an apple but in small size???

Comment: yes..it will. That's that best thing about SURF/SIFT. SIFT is scale-invariant and orientation invariant. Please accept my answer above if its useful for you.

Comment: ok..!!! But SURF would be the best option instand of SIFT!!I know that SURF is faster and robust than SIFT or not??

Comment: yes, i think so. But i haven't worked with ANN yet. You might have aleardy had a look at this link but still < http://qtandopencv.blogspot.de/2013/10/opencv-and-artificial-neural-networkann.html >

Comment: yes it is...i have used SURF and SVM in one application (which wasn't easy) and i got very good results.

Comment: And for examples If I dont care color of object!Can I train VSM with gray-scale images and then put a images in front of camara and convert that images in gray-scale in order to recognize that object??

Comment: Actually SVM is usually trained with descriptors extracted from Gray images and my personal experience was also quite bad when i tried to keep the color information. But the performance is quite good with the descriptors extracted from grayScale images

Comment: mmm let me see if I understand!!well you said that is better to train with gray images??

Comment: Yes, first try to build an application where you convert the color image into grayScale first and then do all other stuff. Later on, when you understand the code/problem then, you can add some extra things like using color information also. But start with grayScale first if you don't have tooooo much knowledge about these things.

Comment: Hey If I use images of apples in order to be recognized by ANN or SVM, so if images contain 2 or more apple ANN or SVM tell that images contain apples??